# Create a batch file to copy results to a directory

Tags: batch-file

I am running tests using selenium. After a test has run, I want to copy results to a directory with today's date. If I run the test again, I want to copy the new results into a new directory with today's date, followed by the run number. So if its the second time I run the test, it will be "today's date - Run 2". Eventually I want to be able to auto-increment the run number in the folder name, but for now I have it hard coded. Also, I know I could use a time stamp in my folder name to help with this, but that is something I don't want to do.

Here is what I have in my batch file. When I run a test and then copy the results for the first time, it successfully creates a folder for variable a, and copies the results into variable a. The issue is when I run tests a second time and try to copy the new results. It successfully creates a folder for variable b and copies the results into variable b, but it is also copying these results into variable a again. Thus overwriting what I already had in that folder.

```
title Copy the Chrome results to the results folder

REM Code for creating a folder with today's date
REM set date=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%\%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
set a=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%
set b=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-Run 2


REM Create HTML directory and copy results
if EXIST "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%a%\Basic_Survey\test_output\html\Chrome\" (
md "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%b%\Basic_Survey\test_output\html\Chrome\"
copy "C:\Automation Workspace\Survey\Basic_Survey\test-output\html\*.*" "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%b%\Basic_Survey\test_output\html\Chrome\"
)
ELSE (
md "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%a%\Basic_Survey\test_output\html\Chrome\"
copy "C:\Automation Workspace\Survey\Basic_Survey\test-output\html\*.*" "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%a%\Basic_Survey\test_output\html\Chrome\"
)

REM Create screenshot directory and copy results
if EXIST "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%a%\Basic_Survey\test_output\screenshots\Chrome\" (
md "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%b%\Basic_Survey\test_output\screenshots\Chrome\"
copy "C:\Automation Workspace\Survey\Basic_Survey\test-output\Report_for_Basic_Survey_Chrome\screenshots\*.*" C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%b%\Basic_Survey\test_output\screenshots\Chrome\
)
ELSE (
md "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%a%\Basic_Survey\test_output\screenshots\Chrome\"
copy "C:\Automation Workspace\Survey\Basic_Survey\test-output\Report_for_Basic_Survey_Chrome\screenshots\*.*" C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%a%\Basic_Survey\test_output\screenshots\Chrome\
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the `date-Run 2` format with the first folder names as just `date` and then automatically increment the run number for each time it is used.

It checks the first location and calculates the correct numeral.
The `xcopy` command creates the folders as it goes.

```
@echo off
title Copy the Chrome results to the results folder

REM Code for creating a folder with today's date
set "a=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%"
set c=0

if not EXIST "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%a%\Basic_Survey\test_output\html\Chrome\" (
   set "name=%a%"
   goto :start
)

:loop
set /a c+=1
set  "name=%a% - Run %c%"
if EXIST "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%name%\Basic_Survey\test_output\html\Chrome\" goto :loop

:start

REM Create HTML directory and copy results
xcopy "C:\Automation Workspace\Survey\Basic_Survey\test-output\html\*.*" "C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%name%\Basic_Survey\test_output\html\Chrome\"

REM Create screenshot directory and copy results
xcopy "C:\Automation Workspace\Survey\Basic_Survey\test-output\Report_for_Basic_Survey_Chrome\screenshots\*.*" C:\SeleniumGrid\Results\%name%\Basic_Survey\test_output\screenshots\Chrome\
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work great. I do have another question. Is is possible to have the first folder named "date" instead of "date Run 1"? And then the second folder would be named "date Run 2".

Comment: The code above has changed and should do as you requested.